# Eliminar vista previa de multiple imágenes antes de upload JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, fileupload, upload

Tengo un script para subir imagenes multiple vía form en js jquery , el cual me muestra un preview de cada imagen, lo que necesito (y no tengo mucho conocimiento en js) que tengan una opción de eliminar individualmente cada una por si hay error en la selección.

Le agradezco a quien me pueda dar una mano.

El HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="uploadImageFile" class="form-control" name="uploadImageFile[]" onchange="showImageHereFunc();" multiple/>

<div id="showImageHere"></div>
```

EL JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  
});
function showImageHereFunc() {
  var total_file=document.getElementById("uploadImageFile").files.length;
  for(var i=0;i<total_file;i++) {
    $('#showImageHere').append("<div class='cardo'><img src='"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+"'></div>");
  }
}
```

Creo que llegué a algo como:

```
function borrar(div){ 
var fi = document.getElementById('uploadImageFile');
fi.removeChild(document.getElementById(div)); 
}
```

Pero no se como implementar el boton, si es que funcionaría....

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? ¿Tenes alguna idea de como quisieras que sea?

Comment: Gracias Marcos por atención, edite la pregunta, pero la verdad no tengo mucha idea de front en js. entonces si serviria no se como implementar esa funcion. Intente de varias maneras que serian muchas para explicitar. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es sencillo, vamos a concatenar a tu `div` (el que estás creando con `append`) con un botón, en el que nos va a servir para eliminar la imagen que estamos mostrando.

Tu tienes esto:

```
$('#showImageHere').append("<div class='cardo'><img src='"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+"'></div>");
```

Al concatenarlo con el botón sería:

```
$('#showImageHere').append("<div class='cardo'><img src='"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+"'><button onclick='borrar(this)'>Eliminar</button></div>");
```

En donde el botón, tiene una función que se ejecutará cuando le hagamos clic, y esa función le pasamos como parámetro `this`, que hace referencia a ese elemento individual (que es tu imagen y tu botón).

```
<button onclick='borrar(this)'>Eliminar</button>
```

Y lo podemos remover de esta manera sencilla:

```
function borrar(div) { 
  div.parentNode.remove();
}
```

En donde `div.parentNode` devuelve **el elemento padre del elemento**. En este caso, `div` (que así se llama su argumento) es el contenedor que encierra a la imagen y al botón, y esto lo removemos con `remove()`.

*Recuerda que con `this` referenciamos a ese elemento individualmente,* es por eso que solo se elimina a ese elemento, mientras que los demás no.

---

**Ejemplo:**

```js
function showImageHereFunc() {
  var total_file=document.getElementById("uploadImageFile").files.length;
  for(var i=0;i<total_file;i++) {
    $('#showImageHere').append("<div class='cardo'><img src='"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+"'><button onclick='borrar(this)'>Eliminar</button></div>");
  }
}

function borrar(div) { 
  div.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="uploadImageFile" class="form-control" name="uploadImageFile[]" onchange="showImageHereFunc();" multiple/>
<div id="showImageHere"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Genial Cris, hasta ahi vamos...el tema es que se elimina el preview de la/las  seleccionada/s  pero al enviar el form por post, van todas las imagenes que se seleccionaron originalmente hasta las eliminadas en la previa. Gracias

Comment: @JorgeB me alegro, recuerda verificar la respuesta si te sirvió marcándole al ✔️ para que tu pregunta esté como respondida, si tienes algún otro problema, no dudes en formular otra pregunta, saludos.